# In Kotlin for Android, I need a look-up table from which, at run time, a number is selected. How can I get this table from resources?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-resources

I'm new to Android programming in Kotlin. For my project, I need to access a pre-filled array of Shorts or Ints to obtain the number in an array element defined by a run-time input. I believe I can enter the array by defining it in onCreate with the statement

```
Startpoint_array:ShortArray=shortArrayOf(1010,1209,1308)
```

The array is not actually 3 elements as shown above; it is 441 elements, and because it is prone to revision it should be in resources. Can somebody explain how to do this?

Comment: See also [the `integer-array` documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#IntegerArray).

Comment: I would put it in assets instead of resources. Less overhead and easier to put a list of numbers in a text file than an XML file.